# Find $a$ and $b$ such that the identity of $x\ast y = xy + xa + ay + b$ is $3$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Find the variables $a$ and $b$ such that the identity element of the composition law $x\ast y = xy + xa +ay +b$ is $3$.

I don't know how to tackle this problem, what's the reasoning for solving this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I presume $x, y, a \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Note that $3\ast y = 3.y + 3.a + a.y + b = (3 + a)y + 3a + b$. If $3$ is the identity element for $\ast$, then $3\ast y = y$ for every $y$, so $(2 + a)y + 3a + b = 0$ for every $y$.

For $y = 0$, the equation reduces to $3a + b = 0 \dots (1)$; for $y = 1$, it becomes $4a + b = -2 \dots (2)$. Solving equations $(1)$ and $(2)$ simultaneously, we see that $a = -2$ and $b = 6$.

Therefore $x\ast y = xy - 2x -2y + 6$. Note that $3\ast y = 3y - 6 - 2y + 6 = y$ as designed, but we also have $x\ast 3 = 3x - 2x - 6 + 6 = x$. Therefore, $3$ is the identity element of $x\ast y = xy - 2x - 2y + 6$.